# command line app to burn part of a long .wav to audio cd

Tags: sound

I have a 7-hour wav file (recording of rain sounds), and I'd like to burn a CD from it.

How can I burn as much as it as will fit onto a standard audio cd so that it will play continuously for the 50mins or so that a CD usually plays for on my ancient CD player?

I'd prefer to be able to do this from the command line.

Answer (score 0):

Use ffmpeg

```
ffmpeg -ss 00:00:00 -t 01:00:00 -i your.wav -acodec copy short.wav
```

Adjust the time ( -t ) until the file is about 700 Mb